# Python, pygame как реализовать код

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в pygame сделать следующий код:

' Если курсор наведен на позицию 100, 100 то при нажатии будет запускаться другой цикл '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки координат можно использовать `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` ,он вернёт кортеж (x,y). Дальше просто проверить с помощью if.
Проверка нажатий через `if i.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`